# Latex on python: \alpha and \beta don't work?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to produce some graphics, and I'm using latex for the legends.

More specifically, I'm trying to use something like this:

```
loglog(x,x, '-r',label='$ \alpha $')
legend()
show()
```

However, this code does not present a legend on the figure, and gets error after I close the image.

I'm using the enthought package (for mac), but the error comes from the pylab/scipy.

The error the appears is exactly:

```
$ lpha $ (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

However, if use the \mu or \gamma, it works well!! I only found about this problem on \beta and \alpha.

Does anyone knows what this can be? I believe python is interpreting "\a" as some character... but I don't know how should I debug / avoid it.

Comment: Have you tried `\\a` instead of `\a`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The issue is that `\a` and `\b` have [special meaning](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html) inside a Python string literal.

I recommend that you use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) whenever there is a backslash embedded inside a string:

```
r'$ \alpha $'
```

Comment: For those trying to reproduce the answer, there is an (obvious) typo maybe worth mentioning:   `r'$ \alpha $'` (the closing quote is missing).

Answer (score 20):

In addition to using raw strings (as mentioned in the post above) you can also escape the backslash.  So typing `\\alpha` and `\\beta` will also work.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me, i.e. '$\beta$', however, '$\\beta$' did.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi if your** `\alpha` **and** `\beta` **don't work on Latex**

```
use $\alpha$
likewise $\beta$ so on.
```

hope it works