# Bold font weight for LaTeX axes label in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

In [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) you can make the text of an axis label bold by

```
plt.xlabel('foo',fontweight='bold')
```

You can also use LaTeX with the right backend

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\phi$')
```

When you combine them however, the math text is not bold anymore

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\phi$',fontweight='bold')
```

Nor do the following LaTeX commands seem to have any effect

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\bf \phi$')
plt.xlabel(r'$\mathbf{\phi}$')
```

**How can I make a bold `$\phi$` in my axis label?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't bold symbols using the bold font, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols) on tex.stackexchange.

As the answer suggests, you could use `\boldsymbol` to bold phi:

```
r'$\boldsymbol{\phi}$'
```

You'll need to load `amsmath` into the TeX preamble:

```
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]
```

Comment: On Matpotlib 3.3.3, with Python 3 7.13.0, adding those commands to rcParams leads to the following error, when trying to plot: `! LaTeX Error: File type1ec.sty not found.`

Comment: @MRule - See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16911 - On Debian and derivatives: `sudo apt install cm-super` - on macOS: `sudo tlmgr install cm-super` - on other systems: see packages listed at https://repology.org/projects/?search=cmsuper or https://repology.org/projects/?search=cm-super or https://repology.org/projects/?search=fontsrecommended

Comment: `matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]` did not work for me (Python 3.9.9), but `matplotlib.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{amsmath}')` did! Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453109/how-to-write-your-own-latex-preamble-in-matplotlib#41453758)

Comment: In addition to `apt-get install cm-super`, I also had to `apt-get install dvipng`. With no additional changes, this provides the `\bf` symbol but not `\mathbf` or `\boldsymbol`. Adding then `rc('text', usetex=True); rc('text.latex',preamble=r"\usepackage{amsmath}")` makes both `\mathbf` and `\boldsymbol` available! It works!

Comment: As of [matplotlib version 3.8.0](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.8.0.html#boldsymbol-mathtext-command-boldsymbol) you no longer need the LaTeX rendering for this to work. It now works with matplotlib's native math parser, too.

Answer (score 19):

If you intend to have consistently bolded fonts throughout the plot, the best way may be to enable latex and add `\boldmath` to your preamble:

```
# Optionally set font to Computer Modern to avoid common missing font errors
matplotlib.rc('font', family='serif', serif='cm10')

matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\boldmath']
```

Then your axis or figure labels can have any mathematical latex expression and still be bold:

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\frac{\phi + x}{2}$')
```

However, for portions of labels that are not mathematical, you'll need to explicitly set them as bold:

```
plt.ylabel(r'\textbf{Counts of} $\lambda$'}
```

Answer (score 19):

In case anyone stumbles across this from Google like I did, another way that doesn't require adjusting the rc preamble (and conflicting with non-latex text) is:

```
ax.set_ylabel(r"$\mathbf{\partial y / \partial x}$")
```

Comment: Having just trawled through a tonne of info on path variables and ways to configure rcParams etc. this was the best solution for me, if nothing else because it doesn't rely on anything else and achieves exactly what is needed. As a heads up to anyone reading this also wanting to use \mathit{}, you can add spaces between words or characters using a double backslash:)

Answer (score 3):

Use either `\bf` ([considered obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text)) or `\bfseries`:

```
plt.xlabel(r'${ \bf K_{1/2} }$')
```

This worked without changing any of the rc parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer seems to include deprecated  parameter setting syntax. I had the same issues found in the comments to that answer.

The following worked for me:

```py
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{amsmath}')
```

Found here:

[How does one use LaTeX/amsmath with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259617/how-does-one-use-latex-amsmath-with-matplotlib/65257846#65257846)

Answer (score 1):

When using LaTeX to typeset all text in a figure, you can make "normal" (non-equation) text bold by using `\textbf`:

```
ax.set_title(r"\textbf{some text}")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update for recent Matplotlib versions

In more recent versions of Matplotlib, the preamble must be specified as a string.

```
plt.rcParams.update(
    {
        "text.usetex": True,
        "text.latex.preamble": r"\usepackage{bm}",

        # Enforce default LaTeX font.
        "font.family": "serif",
        "font.serif": ["Computer Modern"],
    }
)
```

```
plt.xlabel(r"$\bm{\phi}$")
```

This also uses the [default LaTeX font](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces#Introduction) `"Computer Modern"` for a more natural look.

[image]

---

##### Why `\usepackage{bm}` instead of `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Another alternative is:

```
plt.rcParams.update(
    {
        "text.usetex": True,
        "text.latex.preamble": r"\usepackage{amsmath}",
    }
)
```

```
plt.xlabel(r"$\boldsymbol{\phi}$")
```

[image]

But as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10643/2930), `\usepackage{bm}` leads to better placement of superscripts/subscripts and negative signs:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

As this answer [Latex on python: \alpha and \beta don't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836730/latex-on-python-alpha-and-beta-dont-work) points out. You may have a problem with `\b` so `\boldsymbol` may not work as anticipated. In that case you may use something like: `'$ \\\boldsymbol{\\\beta} $'` in your python code. Provided you use the preamble `plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]`

Comment: Thank you for this input (on a 4 year old question!), but using `r` in front of a string should help escape the `\b`. The answer provided by @AndyHayden works fine and identifies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me and I was astonished to find something so simple was so infuriating to achieve. In the end, this is what worked for my use case. I would advise adapting this for your own use:

`plt.suptitle(r"$ARMA({0}, {1})$ Multi-Parameter, $\bf{{a}}$, Electrode Response".format(n_i, m), fontsize=16)`

The `{0}` and `{1}` refer to positional arguments supplied to `format` method, meaning `0` refers to variable `n_i` and `1` refers to variable `m`.

Note: In my setup, for some reason, `\textbf` did not work. I have read somewhere that `\bf` is deprecated in LaTeX, but for me this is what worked.