# How to make figure rectangle in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have drawn the following figure. Is it possible to make the figure with length 2 unit & height 1 unit?  Also is it possible to change plt.xlabel('time (s)') to plt.xlabel('$\alpha \rightarrow$')?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t=[0,1,2]
s=[0.05,0.1,0.2]


plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
#plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Regarding your second question you just need a raw string: `plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha \rightarrow$')`

Comment: Could you clarify your first question?

Comment: Thank you. First problem can be solved by plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))

Comment: You're welcome. You can post an answer to your own question, by the way.

Comment: I have another question. How can I make \alpha bold?

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324477/bold-font-weight-for-latex-axes-label-in-matplotlib

Comment: It is not working. Will you kindly modify my code?

Comment: Ok I just modified it and put it in an answer. Please tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. It is working!

Comment: Cool! You're very welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question about the figure size.

For the second question you just need a raw string, e.g.: `plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha \rightarrow$')`

To make the alpha bold -- as requested in a comment -- it's a little more involved. Per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99286 you'd do:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsbsy}"]

t=[0,1,2]
s=[0.05,0.1,0.2]
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.xlabel(r'$\pmb{\alpha}$ \rightarrow$')
plt.show()
```